# Страница товара в minishop2 обновляется после добавления товара в корзину

Tags: modx, minishop2

Разрабатываю небольшой интернет-магазин на Modx Revolution и приложении minishop2. Это не первый магазин, который делаю на этом приложении, но первый раз столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Кнопка добавления товара в корзину работает не на Ajax, как должно. После нажатия страница перезагружается без всяких уведомлений. 
Однако товар в корзину исправно добавляется.

Как это исправить? 
Привожу в пример фрагмент кода из шаблона товара:

```
<form class="ms2_form" method="post">
        <div class="row has-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 stroller">
                <div class="slider-product-thumbnail">
                    <div class="slider-for-1">
                        [[Gallery? &album=`[[*product-gallery]]` &containerTpl=`productGalleryAlbumTpl` &thumbTpl=`productGalleryThumbTpl` &thumbWidth=`448` &thumbHeight=`448`]]
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider-nav slider-nav-1">
                        [[Gallery? &album=`[[*product-gallery]]` &containerTpl=`productGalleryAlbumTpl` &thumbTpl=`productGalleryThumbTpl` &thumbWidth=`116` &thumbHeight=`116`]]
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 stroller-description">
                [[*content]]
                <p class="text-center lead">
                    <strong>[[getActualPrice]] руб.</strong>
                </p>
                <p class="text-center">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="[[*id]]">
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="[[+price]]">
                    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add">Купить</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Голову сломал в чем проблема. Консоль браузера Javascript ошибок не выдает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался самостоятельно. Методом исключения пришел к выводу, что на странице должен обязательно вызываться сниппет msGallery. Без него форма работала корректно, товар в корзину добавлялся, но страница обновлялась. С ним же проблема исчезла.

Возможно, что кому-нибудь и когда-нибудь этот ответ облегчит жизнь :)

Comment: Может быть, вместе со сниппетом подгружался отсутствующий джиквери? Скорее всего так и есть, 99% к одному!

Comment: @СергейВ. дело было давно, я уже не помню контекст, но проблема была не в jQuery. При ее отсутствии не работали бы другие Javascript-виджеты на странице. Но они работали. И в консоли не было никаких ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

А можна просто в форму огорнути тільки дані які треба для добавлення в корзину: кількість(count), id(id)

```
<div class="row has-content">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 stroller">
    <div class="slider-product-thumbnail">
        <div class="slider-for-1">
            [[Gallery? &album=`[[*product-gallery]]` &containerTpl=`productGalleryAlbumTpl` &thumbTpl=`productGalleryThumbTpl` &thumbWidth=`448` &thumbHeight=`448`]]
        </div>
        <div class="slider-nav slider-nav-1">
            [[Gallery? &album=`[[*product-gallery]]` &containerTpl=`productGalleryAlbumTpl` &thumbTpl=`productGalleryThumbTpl` &thumbWidth=`116` &thumbHeight=`116`]]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 stroller-description">
    [[*content]]
    <p class="text-center lead">
        <strong>[[getActualPrice]] руб.</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="text-center">
        <form class="ms2_form" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="[[*id]]">
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="[[+price]]">
            <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add">Купить</button>
        </form>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Переведите ответ пожалуйста на русский.